# Possible Virus attack

Tags: windows-10, virus, anti-virus, virus-removal

Recently I scanned my Windows PC using Avast and it showed the presence of some weird malware in the result. It couldn't remove all of them nor it could move all the malware to the chest.

Now I am facing some serious trouble:

1. My start menu is not working nor Cortana (search) is opening.
2. Task bar icons are not showing up. I am able to click the task bar icons but I can't see the icons.
3. My internet connection (modem) is getting disconnected by itself.
4. When I click on the personalize settings, it says "This file has no program associated with it."
5. There are some serious troubles.

Please help me. Will restoring to a previous point remove the malware?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: Restoring a previous point might remove the malware if it even exist ( I personally seriously doubt it you are even infected), if it is removed (if it even exists), entirely depends on its location.  Most of your problems are caused by corrupt system files, caused by a HDD that is starting to fail, none of the things you state is happening are normally caused by malware.

Comment: Yeah, most probably your registry associations for files got mangled up. I'm not sure if there is an easy fix to this. Windows 10 has an option to reset itself to default settings - I would try that.

Comment: sure that i'm not infected and i have your first issue

Comment: Guys,Avast scan shows existence of malware.Windows key is not working.

Comment: Win:32 Browse Fox 
When I try to remove,it says access denied.There are many more.

Comment: @Ramhound There are many more malware like the above one.Modem getting disconnected is not normal.I have no idea about these malwares.

Comment: restart in safe mode with networking - download and install malwarebytes - update, run. report the results

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Can you give me some details?...I am not good at all this.Please!

Comment: Is there someone who could help me?Avast shows infected files in C drive.

Comment: Format C:>reinstall Windows

Comment: @Moab Is that the only possible way out?

Comment: @MathewsMathai - You are right.  You don't know about malware.  I do know something, about malware, what you describe is very unlikely to be caused by malware.

Comment: @Ramhound Avast shows positive result.My windows key too is not responding.As a reason,I can't even take a screenshot...Do you have teamviewer installed?

Comment: You can post a screenshot, just a url to it, in a comment.  I don't trust Avast enough, I have seen far to many false positives, to comment on what it found is causing these problems ( but based on my decade+ of experience ) it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Ramhound 31% C drive scanned,5 infected files reported.I am not able to capture a screenshot as my windows key is not functioning and many other problems have developed.That's the reason I suspect it's a malware attack.

Comment: `%windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe` can help you take screenshots.

Comment: Boot into safe mode by repeatedly pressing f8 during power on. Select safe mode with networking at the menu. Plugin network cable from router into computer. Once into windows - everything will look bigger - don't worry about this and open a web browser. go to http://www.malwarebytes.org and download their software.

You can also try the above URL and install normally - some viruses etc. block you doing this. Try and install malwarebytes.

Comment: @MathewsMathai its the only safe way out, even if you remove the virus there may be unrepairable damage.

Comment: Okay.Thanks a lot guys.I'll start with the safe mode and then finally,if nothing works I'll format C:

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Thanks a lot.I ran malwarebytes without switching to safe mode.It tracked down a trojan and cleaned the system.Now everything is back to normal.It was indeed a malware attack!...It had locked down all my system controls.Now everything is working pretty cool!Thanks again.